# Upload base64 Image to Firebase React native

Tags: javascript, firebase, image, react-native, firebase-storage

I try to upload a "base64" image to Firebase by using React Native on iOS. But when I try to upload the image, I get following error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'uri.substring')

I get my image by using `route.params` and if I display the image in a view like this, the image is displayed.

```
<Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: `data:image/png;base64,${myImage}` }}/>
```

Should I do anything else if the image is in "base64" or what else should I do?

This is my code:

```
// Here is how I get the image
const { myImage } = props.route.params;

const uploadImage = async () => {
  const {uri} = myImage;
  const filename = uri.substring(uri.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  const uploadUri = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? uri.replace('file://', '') : uri;
  setUploading(true);

  setTransferred(0);
  const task = storage()
    .ref(filename)
    .putFile(uploadUri);
  // set progress state
  task.on('state_changed', snapshot => {
    setTransferred(
      Math.round(snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 10000
    );
  });
  try {
    await task;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
  setUploading(false);
  Alert.alert(
    'Photo uploaded!',
    'Your photo has been uploaded to Firebase Cloud Storage!'
  );
};
```

Comment: So `result` is a string that contains base64 encoded characters?

Comment: Yes, that's right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your current code, you take `myImage` out of `props.route.params`, and this is a string of Base 64 characters corresponding to a PNG image (such as `iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAMSURBVBhXY/j//z8ABf4C/qc1gYQAAAAASUVORK5CYII=` - the data of a PNG for a single #FFFFFF pixel).

```js
const { myImage } = props.route.params;
```

Below that you try to get a property `uri` out of this `myImage` string. As this property doesn't exist, you will get `undefined`. This `uri = undefined` value then throws an error on the next line.

```js
const { uri } = myImage; // uri is undefined! ("".uri === undefined)
const filename = uri.substring(uri.lastIndexOf('/') + 1); // throws error!
```

The correct way to upload a Data URL would be to use the [`Reference#putString()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#putstring) method as covered in the [documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_from_a_string).

Applying this to your code, you would use:

```js
const { myImage } = props.route.params;

const uploadImage = async () => {
  const dataUrl = `data:image/png;base64,${myImage}`;

  // you could use a Firestore Doc ID, a RTDB Push ID or
  // some `uuid` implementation to generate a suitable filename.
  const storageRef = storage()
    .ref(/* provide a path for the image */);

  const uploadTask = storageRef
    .putString(dataUrl, 'data_url');

  uploadTask.on('state_changed', snapshot => {
    setTransferred(
      Math.round(snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 10000
    );
  });

  try {
    await uploadTask;
    
    setUploading(false);
    Alert.alert(
      'Photo uploaded!',
      'Your photo has been uploaded to Firebase Cloud Storage!'
    );
  } catch (err) {
    // TODO: Check value of `err.code` and handle appropriately.
    console.error('Upload failed: ', err);
    Alert.alert(
      'Photo upload failed!',
      'Your photo didn\'t upload properly!'
    );
  }
}
```

To prevent overwriting someone else's data and make security rules easier to implement, you should prefix the uploaded file with the user's ID similar to:

```js
const storageRef = storage()
    .ref('userUploads')
    .child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    .child(/* generated image ID */);

// builds a reference to /userUploads/someUserId/someImageId
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I really appreciate it. I added this path to the "ref".                                                   const childPath = `paintBoards/${
      auth().currentUser.uid
    }/${Math.random().toString(36)}`;                                                                                 But when I try to upload it throws me an error like:                                                             Error: [storage/unknown] An unknown error has occurred.

Comment: @Alexander Normally the [Cloud Storage Error Codes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/handle-errors) are more useful than that. Because the error is `storage/unknown`, the cause is unclear and you'll need to reach out to [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact) for details. It could be a simple as a [Cloud Storage Security Rules permissions problem](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security).

Comment: I changed security rules to "allow read, write: if true;". But it still gives me a error. When installed a new npm package I get this tw warnings: @react-native-firebase/storage@12.2.0 requires a peer of @react-native-firebase/app@12.2.0 but none is installed ..... AND                                                                                                                                 [!] NPM package '@react-native-firebase/storage' depends on '@react-native-firebase/app' v12.2.0 but found v12.1.0, this might cause build issues or runtime crashes. I have run npm and pod install.

Comment: You seem to have two versions of `@react-native-firebase/storage` defined in your `package.json` file. One that specifically names v12.2.0 and the other that uses the latest (which is also v12.2.0). In `package.json`, you also have `@react-native-firebase/app@12.1.0` which should be updated to `@react-native-firebase/app@12.2.0` or simply `@react-native-firebase/app`. Because it's not a client permissions error, it must be a server-side permissions error.

Comment: Mm okey, so what should I do? I have removed/ reinstall the package, but it still gives me the same error. Anything else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

If your image data string looks something like this:
`data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABQAAAALQCAYAAADPfd1WAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAIABJREFUeF7svXmPLEly4GcRkVnnO/r1656+5uRcJEGAnMEO ...`

Then you can use the `putString` method - but you need to remove the starting info `data:image/png;base64,` first.

```
await storage.ref("pictures/thumbnail.png").putString(thumbnailImageData.split("data:image/png;base64,")[1], "base64");
```