# How to convert base64 image data to data URL in react native?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, react-native

I am using react-native-signature-canvas which returns the signature as a base64 image string. I want to send it to the API and before that, I want to convert it to the data URL. Can anyone help me? Also, I don't want to store the file/image to the local storage..just wanna convert it to the DataUrl and send it to the API.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upload base64 Image to Firebase React native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68470172/upload-base64-image-to-firebase-react-native)

Comment: no...is there a way i can send it as formdata??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32441963/how-to-use-formdata-in-react-native

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to convert `base64ImageString` to `DataUrl`

```
const DataUrl = `data:image/png;base64,${base64ImageString}`;
```

Ref : [Upload base64 Image to Firebase React native](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68470872/10657559)

Answer (score 0):

1. install `react-native-fs`

```js
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';
import {Platform} from 'react-native';

  const createTempImage = async base64String => {
    try {

      let base64 = base64String.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
      const fileName = `${Date.now()}.png`;
      
      // creates a file in temporary directory to delete later
      const path = `${RNFS.TemporaryDirectoryPath}/${fileName}`;
      await RNFS.writeFile(path, base64, 'base64');
      
      const image = {
        uri: Platform.OS == 'ios'? path: 'file://' + path,
        name: fileName,
        type: 'image/png',
      };

     return image
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

2. You can delete the file when the request done

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).